# No such file or directory g++ Include Directory

Tags: makefile, g++

I am new to C++ programming and making MakeFiles, so straight to the point:
here is my MakeFile:

```
CC = g++
INCLUDES = -I\ include/
CFLAGS = -Wall \ -g\ $(INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS = -L./lib
main: main.o
        $(CC) main.o $(LDFLAGS) -o main
main.o: src/main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp -o main.o
```

Sorry for noobness :( . my File structure:

```
src/
include/
Makefile
```

and "make" shows :

```
g++: error:  -g -I include/: No such file or directory
```

Kindly please also give suggestions for improving this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont require `\` after every option 
Please see below changes:

```
CC = g++
INCLUDES = include/
CFLAGS = -Wall  -g -I$(INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS = -L./lib

main: main.o
    $(CC) main.o $(LDFLAGS) -o main
main.o: src/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp -o main.o
```

Comment: But what do I do if I want to add location and argument at  same time in variable like in LDFLAGS in above example

Comment: @jalok2008 : you can just add it with spaces in between . Eg: ``-I$(INCLUDES) -I$(INCLUDES)/machine ...``